# NOTIFICACIONES PUSH A USUARIOS ESPECÍFICOS CON PHP

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando una aplicación web de helpdesk usando php puro, y quiero implementar notificaciones push, pero que estas notificaciones les aparezcan a un usuario en particular cada que se le responda a través de la web, alguien sabe de alguna tecnología, ¿o que necesito usar de php para hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siga los pasos a continuación para lograr esto,

1. Obtenga el token del dispositivo usando Firebase SDK y guárdelo en su base de datos mysql contra el usuario ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client )
2. Seleccione tokens de dispositivo que coincidan con sus criterios (consulta SQL)
3. Envíe el mensaje push al dispositivo seleccionado usando rest api de firebase( https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send , ¿Cómo puedo enviar una notificación de Firebase Cloud Messaging sin usar el ¿Consola de Firebase? )

Comment: Interesante, quiero enviar notificaciones a ordenadores o laptops, la manera de obtener token con firebase SDK, ¿también sirve para obtener el Token de esos dispositivos?